# Stacking JLayer classes (to a JPanel)

Tags: java, swing, jlayer

I was hoping to stack instances of `JLayers` ontop of each other to get a layered effect but they don't seem to want to work that way. I'd like to *decorate* a single `JPanel` with multiple effects implemented by multiple `LayerUI<JPanel>` classes.

For example

```
frame.add(new JLayer<>(panel, new LayerUI<> ...));
frame.add(new JLayer<>(panel, new LayerUI<> ...));
```

where the argument to `new JLayer` is the same `JPanel` instance but the `LayerUI` instances do different things.

It seems the last one added wins. They both draw directly to the context in the `paint` method, perhaps thats it..?

See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/jlayer.html) for Oracles' tutorial

Comment: This cannot be done for a different reason: same UI element (panel in this case) cannot be used more then once in the same UI hierarchy

Comment: for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short, runnable, compilable

Comment: It's been a few years since this was posted, but I'd interested in an answer to this.  I've been searching around for a clean way to add multiple decorations to a JPanel/JComponent with no luck for hours now.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with JLayer since it's new with Java 1.7.

However, you can write your own Layer class that contains a BufferedImage and a z level.

Your draw method would go through a List or Map of Layers, drawing them on a JPanel in z level order.